# What is the difference between java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue and java.util.concurrent.Exchanger?

Tags: java, concurrency

I think SynchronousQueue can contain only one object for exchange.

Comment: Why do you think that? You've left out a lot of explanation and research effort in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html):

> An `Exchanger` may be viewed as a bidirectional form of a [`SynchronousQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html). Exchangers may be useful in applications such as genetic algorithms and pipeline designs.

Comment: Thanks user7790438 !

Comment: glade to help you